# MYSQL select distinct(indexed_column) from table with 1 million rows

Tags: mysql, optimization

Edit:
actually aside from select distinct(which I haven't verified yet), the main performance bottle neck might be the network speed, when server and client are both on localhost,
select all 2 milion records took 36 seconds, however, on a (supposedly high speed) network with client sitting on another box, the query is not yet done after 10 minutes.
  This is supposedly 100mbps network but when I checked the client(java jdbc), it's receiving data at a rate of 3kb/second.    The mysql server, however, is sending at a speed of 100kb/sec(including other client connections though).
Why is the java jdbc client receiving data at such a low rate?

```
select distinct(indexed_column) from mytable
```

is very slow on mytable with only 1 million rows, the indexed_column is a non-unique index.
is there a way to optimize it?
an explain gives this:

```
id | select_type | table        | type  | possible_keys | key               | key_len | ref  | rows    | Extra     
|  1 | SIMPLE      | mytable | range | NULL          | my_index | 50      | NULL | 1759002 | Using index for group-by |
```

does type=range means it's not using index?  is this why it's slow?

Comment: What does EXPLAIN say about the queryplan? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/explain.html

Comment: what is 'very slow' ? and what is the data type of the column ?

Comment: @Frank: that's all explan select said

Comment: @Krtek: the data type is varchar(50), it took 3 hours and still going.

Comment: 3 hours ?? seems impossible to me for only 1 million rows, are you sure the database is not locked or corrupt ?

Comment: `range` does use an index, http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/explain-output.html#jointype_range , see also `Using index for group-by`. DISTINCT works like GROUP BY. The problem is that the database thinks is has to select almost 2 million records. Is that correct? EXPLAIN EXTENDED can give some extra information

Comment: 3 hours? That sounds like a lock, not a problem with the query above.

Comment: I checked using show processlist, no lock is shown, is there a better way to check?

Comment: @Frank: yes the database does have to select almost 2 million records. EXPLAIN EXTENDED showed the same thing as EXPLAIN

Comment: I just killed another select(distinct) query although it was not locking anything.  Now there are no active queries except this one, but it's still running with no end in sight..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would build a unique index on the table, on the column you want "DISTINCT" of...

Hence your looking for DISTINCT on a given column.  If you build a UNIQUE INDEX on a column(or columns) you are looking for distinct combinations, the indexed pages will only hold a pointer to the first record that qualifies for such combination.

Ex: if you have

```
Category   Count
1          587
2          321
3          172
4          229
5          837
```

Your UNIQUE INDEX on category will only have 5 records... in this case, even though over 2,000 entries across 5 categories,  the DISTINCT CATEGORY count is 5, the index has 5, you're done.  Apply this concept to your table of 1 MILLION + records.

Comment: actually I just realized that the index is unique,  the problem is that my data are almost distinct(almost no dups), I guess it's the select distinct that's slow because after I changed the query to just SELECT, it finished in 36 seconds.  select DISTINCT never got to finish(I killed it after 6 hours), it's only about 2 million records and I can't use SELECT DISTINCT?

Comment: actually it might be a network speed issue, please see my edit